# How do I follow links in Scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

```
class AmazonspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    start_urls = ['https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?k=9780297833697']

    def parse(self, response):
        Items = AmazonappItem()

        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
        book = soup.find("a", {"class": "a-link-normal a-text-normal"})
        link = book.get('href')
        myurl = "https://www.amazon.co.uk" + link
        Items['bookurl'] = myurl
```

I found the new link in myurl and now I need to follow this new link. How to do it?

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/master/intro/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to `yield` `scrapy.Request` object:

```
def parse(self, response):
    Items = AmazonappItem()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    book = soup.find("a", {"class": "a-link-normal a-text-normal"})
    link = book.get('href')
    myurl = "https://www.amazon.co.uk" + link
    Items['bookurl'] = myurl
    yield scrapy.Request(url=myurl, callback=self.your_callback_for_that_url)
```

Comment: what is this "your_callback_for_that_url"?  what should I write instead of it?

Comment: You need to write a code (`def your_callback_for_that_url(self, response): ...`) that will process URL like that.

Comment: I do this as you say but it gives following error:" yield scrapy.Request(url=myurl, callback=self.visit)
AttributeError: 'AmazonspiderSpider' object has no attribute 'visit'
"

Comment: code: "class AmazonspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Amazonspider'
    start_urls = ['https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?k=9780297833697'

                  ]


    def parse(self, response):
        Items = AmazonappItem()

        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
        book = soup.find("a", {"class": "a-link-normal a-text-normal"})
        link = book.get('href')
        myurl = "https://www.amazon.co.uk" + link
        Items['bookurl'] = myurl
        yield {'Book': myurl
                  }

        yield scrapy.Request(url=myurl, callback=self.visit)

Comment: yield scrapy.Request(url=myurl, callback=self.visit)
        def visit(self, response):
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
            book = soup.find("span", {"id": "productTitle"}).get_text()
            print(book)

Comment: Sorry but if you want to get some help here you need to **format** your question correctly. Do not place your code into comments but update your original question instead.